# Is there a way to dynamically allocate or assign values to ivars of a class at runtime in Cocoa / Cocoa Touch?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I'm sure we can dynamically determine iVars of a class at run time. Is there any way to allocate the determined iVars during run time?
TIA..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer and the one you probably want is: 
`[obj setValue:@"woof" forKey:@"dog"];`**

and for ramblings...

you can using the runtime find all of the iVars of a class with:

`Ivar * class_copyIvarList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)`

eg:

```
id someObj; //assigned elsewhere
unsigned int count = 0;
Ivar * iVarList = class_copyIvarList([someObj class],&count);
for(;count>0;count--)
{
    Ivar testVar = iVarList[count]; 
    //do something with test Ivar
}
free(iVarList);
```

I am almost sure that you wouldn't ever want to do that except perhaps in a debugging scenario... introspecting the private frameworks etc.

or if you know the name of the iVar you can use:

 `Ivar object_setInstanceVariable(id obj, const char *name, void *value)` or the more objc way of `[obj setValue: @"woof" forKey:@"dog"]` which will eventually fail through to setting the iVar.

what you could potentially do, and I have had to do in the past is to introspect the properties list:

with an analogous call to: `objc_property_t * class_copyPropertyList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)` this can be useful for copying unknown objects, and for debugging.